# Make a DontDestroyOnLoad script to run a function every time scene is started

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a module in Unity Project that has DontDestroyOnLoad in its Start().

How can I write a func (of which of the existing ones is there) that would run every time a new scene is loaded?

I've tried both Start() and OnEnable() and it didn't seem to work?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to separate the responsbilities into 2 different scripts. One that runs every time the scene is loaded, and the other that contains the persisted responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Unity's `SceneManager` has a notification to which you can add a delegate function to run when a scene is loaded.

You can find an example on how to use it in Unity's documentation: [SceneManager.sceneLoaded delegate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)